# macbook pro (early 2015) hangs on startup; disk utility finds problems with partition map

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, startup

As the title says, my MacBook pro (13" retina display, early 2015) suddenly started hanging halfway through startup (apple logo and progress bar), and there seems to be no way to access the data. Here is some info from disk recovery attempts:

- it will not boot into safe mode.
- it recognizes that there is a hard drive (start of recovery) but then cannot find it to install a new os.
- disk repair (in recovery mode) says all is ok except it says "**problems were found with the partition map which may prevent booting**"
- MacBook does not show up on another mac in target mode

Before I shell out $3K to recover data, I thought I'd ask if there is anything else that I could try. I've seen similar posts [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SahR3.jpg) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zEhh.jpg), but I'm not an expert and it seems my situation might be a little different...and I'd like some advice before I start running commands and make it fubar. I've included some info about the system below (sorry they're photos, but it's the only way to get the info off the laptop). Commands run in the pics are:

1. gpt -r show /dev/disk1
2. diskutil info /dev/disk1s1
3. diskutil info /dev/disk0
4. diskutil list
5. continuation of #4 and fdisk /dev/disk0
6. gpt -r show disk0
7. part of the verbose bootup sequence

I'm hoping that there is some command I can use to create/ID a partition on disk0 to install the OS. Another idea I had was to maybe remove the HD and use an external OWC enclosure to look at it. Any advice you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jan

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like your system is in the new APFS volume format, but you're getting an older version of Recovery (probably via the Internet rather than the built-in one) that doesn't know how to handle it. Check with the `sw_vers` command -- partial APFS support was added in v10.12, full support in v10.13. Restarting with Option-Command-R held down *should* get you the latest compatible version of Internet Recovery, but in my experience that doesn't always work. What version is the other Mac (the one you were using Target mode with) running?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, the macbook is v10.11.6 (although I could've sworn I upgraded it to at least 10.15) and the iMac trying to read it is v11.5.2. I've tried option-cmd-r and it didn't work (neither did shift-opt-cmd-r).

Comment: Can you use the iMac to create a bootable installer of 10.15 on a flash drive and use it to boot the MBP? (https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) Gordon's comment is very important. It is dangerous to access an APFS volume made with a later version of macOS from an earlier version because the format is unstable and mixing format versions can corrupt data structures on disk.

Comment: @pion I'll give it a try and get back to you. thanks.

Comment: @pion So I loaded 10.15 onto a thumb drive, started it up per the instructions, and while the volume with bootable installer showed up, clicking it just went to the normal loading screen where it hanged halfway.

Comment: @praguequest Can you try to boot from the thumb drive again but this time in verbose mode? (Hold CMD+V as soon as you select the thumb drive in the boot picker and)

Comment: @ pion The end of your message appears to be cut off, but I assume you wanted me to capture the code somehow and post it. It went by fast so I tried to take as many pics as I could. 
While it initially worked as before, the verbose method ran with code output (images 1-4), stopped at a certain point (image4), then proceeded rapidly with more code (that I just couldn't capture) until it ended up on the loading screen (apple logo + loading bar) but the bar did not show progress. Then it crashed, restarted, and hung halfway as before.

Comment: @pion i've included the images in the main body of the thread (replaced the previous ones)

Comment: @praguequest Sorry, the rest of my cut-off message was going to be: "and take slow-motion video of the boot process and then upload framegrabs from that video so that we can see the end of the sequence where we might get some clues as to what's failing"

Comment: @pion ok, last attempt here. finally managed to get a semi-decent vidcap of the very first, and very last lines of the startup sequence. hope you can read it...if not, thanks for trying.

Comment: @pion in the event that this cannot be resolved through some coding means, do you think physically removing the HD and using a USB-connected OWC external enclosure would work? Sort of like connecting an HD to a SATA cable and using it as a slave on Windows machines.